# Android Performance Question : Many small apps or one big app?

Tags: android, performance

I read this quote in one of the webpages:

> If you are writing a large
>   application, consider dividing it into
>   a suite of applications and services.
>   Smaller applications load faster and
>   use fewer resources. Making a suite of
>   applications, content providers, and
>   services makes your code more open to
>   incorporation into other applications
>   as described the "Use and be used"
>   tip.

Is this true? What is the thumb rule for the size of app?

Answer (score 1):

Well technically this has no `best` answer.

But I would go with many small apps:

- easier to update (you update only components you need, less bandwidth too)
- more spot in the Market for your products
- more rating to your person as a developer
- increased monetization
- keep as many sub apps as possible to old SDK versions to be back compatible (at least that part)
- less negative feedback if only a component fails to work, contrary when a big app fails to load
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

As for me I also prefer many small applications instead of *one big to rule them all*. Depending on the requirements the one big approach has one advantage and that is:

- You only need to install one app.

Apart from that I can't see any other reason.